# Wordpress - How To Get Parent Category ID

Tags: wordpress

> Wordpress - How To Get Parent Category ID

---

```
my category is  
news
---->sport news
```

i have a post in **sport** news.

how to get the **parent**(news) id when i go into the post of sport news?

this code echo parent cat name

```
      foreach((get_the_category()) as $childcat) { $parentcat = $childcat->category_parent;  
echo get_cat_name($parentcat);
echo $parentcat->term_id;}   
        echo $post->post_parent->cat_ID;
```

this code echo single page cat name

```
   global $post;$category = get_the_category($post->ID);echo $category[0]->name;
```

this chode echo id of cat name

```
        $category = get_the_category();    echo $category[0]->cat_ID;
```

i need echo parent id (cat_ID)
 plz help me

thanks.

Answer (score 19):

Simply, very simply.

```
//firstly, load data for your child category
$child = get_category(31);

//from your child category, grab parent ID
$parent = $child->parent;

//load object for parent category
$parent_name = get_category($parent);

//grab a category name
$parent_name = $parent_name->name;
```

Study [`get_category`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_category)

Comment: Is it REALLY working? The `get_category` function gets the `post_id` as the argument and returns the `category_id`. So here in the next `get_category` function, it is passing the `$parent` which is the parent id of `category_id` and not the `post_id`. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 9):

```
$thiscat =  get_query_var('cat'); // The id of the current category
$catobject = get_category($thiscat,false); // Get the Category object by the id of current category
$parentcat = $catobject->category_parent; // the id of the parent category
```

Comment: Thank you so much,

Answer (score 1):

For Wordpress 5.9.

Getting parent category id:

```
$cat = get_queried_object();
$parentCatId = $cat->parent;
```

Getting current category id:

```
$cat = get_queried_object();
$catId = $cat->term_id
```

Getting category name by id:

```
$name = get_the_category_by_ID($catId);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
    if (is_category()) 
    {
    $thiscat = get_category( get_query_var( 'cat' ) );
    $catid = $thiscat->cat_ID;
    $parent = $thiscat->category_parent;
    if (!empty ($catid) ) {
    $catlist = get_categories(
                                array(
                                'child_of' => $catid,
                                'orderby' => 'id',
                                'order' => 'ASC',
                                'exclude' => $parent,
                                'hide_empty' => '0'
                                ) );

        ?>
            <div class="subcat-list">
                <ul>
                    <?php foreach ($catlist as $category) { ?>
                      <li><a href="<?php echo get_category_link( $category->term_id ); ?>"><?php echo $category->name; ?></a></li>
                      <?php } ?> 
                 </ul>
            </div>
            <?php } } ?>
```

Comment: please add an explanation to your answer of how it solves the question.

Answer (score 0):

I know it is asked a long time ago but because none of the answers worked for me, decided to share what I've done:

```
$post_id = 1000;
$category = get_category($post_id);

$category_parent_id = $category[0]->parent;

// It gets the name and not the id or the object
$category_name = get_the_category_by_ID($category_parent_id);

// And here is the parent of the category
$category_parent = get_category_by_path($category_name);
```